# How can I know if this dream has a meaning after salatu alistikhara?

Tags: halal-haram, tafseer, dream, non-mahram

Assalamu alaikum.
Im a 25 year old moroccan girl who was born and raised in an European country.
Im in a relationship with a 30 year old angolan guy who I think is really a good man. He comes from a religious protestant family. His dad died when he was little and his mom died few years ago.
From the moment he met me he knew i was muslim, and he always told me that i came to his life for a reason and that he wants to convert, he is still in the process , and he is ready to convert and accept islam and get married with me,but my mom doesent agree on being with him.
I've never had any relationship like this before, and I've never pushed my self so far..in fact the only regret is that we have done things that only married couples can do..and we both feel guily for that, but we are really both sure about each others feelings and that we want to live our lives together.
I already know his family and he wants to meet my mom since months to ask my hand. We are looking for future and plans ,kids and everything else.
From the first months we felt like husband and wife, and now I want to find the right way,since my mom seems not to accept this relationship.

I want god to bless us so we decided to limit our interactions,and try to make it as halal as possible. So we are trying to correct our relationship.
Besides that we try to live a righteous life and improve day by day. We did mistakes and I kept feeling guily for our love till this time. I dont want to make God angry, so I did Salatu Al istikhara and asked God, if  he is the right one for me,show me, and if he is the wrong one for me and he will not be good for my religion take him away from my life.
The same night I had multiple dreams but one of them was the last one and was stuck in my mind. I've dreamt about my eye(maybe the right one im not sure) that was somehow misplaced but still inside my eye cavity, but it was like shifted towards the nose and stuck, so my mom came to me willing to fix it. That was the dream, really short but I remembered it.
Before this dream i had another one that doesent make any particular sense to me so didnt feel was important.

I kept obsessed on this last one. Does it mean anything?